# When I need site optimization (image cache)?

Tags: http, optimization, graphics

Say, I have a simple website for my company with images:

---*3 in in header (website logo, facebook/google+ logos);*

---*5 additional images for characterization.*

The total size of images less than 1MB. So, should I use image cache in my website? What are the minimum requirements when website needs image cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache can be implemented on different levels.

The main idea is to store some results (generated content, calculations, etc) for some time, in order to serve these values more quickly, assuming they haven't changed in the meantime (or your scenario doesn't care about the data being slightly out of date).

From your description I deduce we are talking about a static webpage, and in this case, there is no real need for cache.

What you might want to do though, is a CDN, which can keep copies of elements (like images, or entire webpages) in a distributed network, and then use various mechanisms to minimize the time of delivery to the end user.

It's well described [here, on the website of Cloudflare, one of the CDN providers](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn/). You can even setup a simple "cache" layer for free.

And to answer you question about the minimum requirements, there isn't such thing. It all depends on what's most important for you in your use case. Sometimes a very simple webpage needs to be heavily optimized, because it's visited very often, and sometimes, even a complicated one doesn't really need caching.
General rule of thumb, I think, would be to see whether the value of the resources saved will cover for the cost of implementing it.